# Pip command not found using root

Tags: python, pip

I want to run pip using root for some reason. But when i run `sudo pip install ......` it gives me `pip: command not found`. without root it runs fine but i want to run as root for some reason please help !

Comment: Can you try `sudo python -m pip install ...` (for Python 2, replace with `python3` for 3) instead? Though it's usually not a good idea to run pip as root, you should probably use `python -m pip install --user` instead to install the packages to your user's home directory without root rights, or install the deb package with `sudo apt install python-...` instead.

Comment: Which reason again?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me how i solved it was

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install PyYAML
```

I will try to make a symlink for next time.